# How to localize pr2 on gazebo?

Tags: ros, fake-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed [Faking Sensor Info in Simulation](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_simulator/Tutorials/FakingSensorInfo).

I run

```
  roslaunch pr2_gazebo pr2_empty_world.launch
  roslaunch pr2_teleop teleop_keyboard.launch
  rosrun fake_localization fake_localization
  rostopic echo amcl_pose
```

It doesn't show any result.

How to solve it?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37908/how-to-localize-pr2-on-gazebo?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-07-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The odometry frame for the PR2 is not `odom` but `odom_combined`. You need to set the corresponding parameter for fake_localization. For instance, the following launch file should work:

```
<launch>
  <node name="fake_localizaton" type="fake_localization" pkg="fake_localization">
    <rosparam>
      odom_frame_id: odom_combined
      base_frame_id: base_footprint
    </rosparam>
  </node>
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2